# Get all combinations of list items with their names

Tags: python, variables

I want to get all the combinations of a list of values. I was able to do that via this code:

```py
list_of_all_features_to_combine = [name1, name2, name3]
    
    
import itertools
all_combinations = []
for L in range(0, len(list_of_all_features_to_combine)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(list_of_all_features_to_combine, L):        
         all_combinations.append(subset)
```

I print one combination as follows:

```py
print(all_combinations[0])
```

Of course, I only get the values.

My problem is that I want to know "which" items are combined, so I need the variable names. The only way to do that, that I can imagine, is to have a list of dictionaries with the names as string and then combine these, but I'm sure, that there is a simpler and more elegant way of doing that.
Maybe some method of how to retrieve the variable names, such that I get an output like
`name1, name2 : (1,2)`

Comment: What type of object are `name1`, `name2` and `name3` features? Are they always the same type?

Comment: they are a mixture of lists and np arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
from itertools import combinations

name1, name2, name3 = 10,20,30
names = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
list_of_all_features_to_combine = [name1, name2, name3]

my_globals = globals()
name_combs = [subset for L in range(len(names)+1) 
              for subset in combinations(names,L)]
result = {t:tuple(my_globals[var] for var in t) for t in name_combs }
```

The result looks like this:

```
print (result)

{(): (),
 ('name1',): (10,),
 ('name2',): (20,),
 ('name3',): (30,),
 ('name1', 'name2'): (10, 20),
 ('name1', 'name3'): (10, 30),
 ('name2', 'name3'): (20, 30),
 ('name1', 'name2', 'name3'): (10, 20, 30)}
```

To access only the combinations of values:

```
print (list(result.values()))

[(), (10,), (20,), (30,), (10, 20), (10, 30), (20, 30), (10, 20, 30)]
```

To access only the combinations of names:

```
print (list(result.keys()))
[(), ('name1',), ('name2',), ('name3',), ('name1', 'name2'), ('name1', 'name3'), ('name2', 'name3'), ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Your printed result looks indeed like something i want! :) But the code doesnt run. maybe you could explain the logic behind the "name_combs = "part? because I get an "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" and im not sure whether you refer to my variable "all_combinations" with your variable "combinations". Thanks!

Comment: ok, found out why it doesnt run: im missing the "extra declaration" name1, name2, name3 = 10,20,30, my variables are defined elsewhere. is there another way instead of defining them again? because they are already global. thanks

Comment: Could you pls provide more details on the variables? By "defined elsewhere", I suppose you mean that the variables are defined in another module. If that is so, are you importing the variables? If importing, could you provide the exact import statement that you're using?

Comment: sorry, I mean that i just define them before i do the combinations. in the same script, not in a method or other module.

Comment: i tried to give them all the global keyword but now i have a key error. not sure why. could you please secify your var "combinations"?

Comment: In the place of my line of code `name1, name2, name3 = 10,20,30`, you can have any other alternative code to initialize the variables, as long as, in the end, the variables happen to global in the scope of the same module. For example, instead of that line, you could have three separate lines like `name1 = 10`, `name2=20`, and `name3=30`. You just need to ensure that these are global variables. Perhaps you should edit your question to include the exact part of the code that introduces those variables. There's always a chance that our conversation in the comments section is confusing.

Comment: it worked! thank you so much. I just had to replace "name1, name2, name3 = 10,20,30" with "global name1 global name2 global name3". thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got you correctly, but is this what you looking for?
Or maybe part of it?

```
l = ["name1", "name2", "name3"] 
x = [x for x in itertools.permutations(l, r=3)]
for i in enumerate(x):
    print(i)
```

If you can explain maybe more specific?